# Use fields as default value expression for parameters in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, jaspersoft-studio

I recently migrated from using iReport on Windows to using Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. After finding my way around most of the changes, I got all my reports working, except for one thing. In iReport, I used to create a parameter, then under its properties, I would set the default expression value to be a field. That way when the query runs, it will assign this value to the parameter, and this value would be passed to subreports. In Jaspersoft Studio, that option is not available.  (see screeshots below).

[image]
[image]

Even Variables are not there. What I was expecting to find is a window similar to this:

[image]

How to I get the fields option back?

Comment: I don't really get what is your use case, I have no idea why someone would want to assign a field to a parameter. Just to make it clear: `Fields` represent columns returned by the query; `Parameters` - values passed to the report "from outside", by an application creating the report. In most cases parameters are used inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got this to work, the only way i could do this was through use of sub report

My design is as follow:

1. Main report, this report returns results stored in a field , of
   variable
2. Sub report, this report has a parameter created , this parameter i'm
   pushing the result of field from main report

How to link:

1. In your mail report create/add your sub-report
2. In your sub-reports settingsyou need to link the fields to the parameters,   parameter from sub_report = field from main_report
3. When you now run the main report, contents of field in main report will be passed to sub report, in my case i wanted to filter sub_report results based on contents of return field from mail report

I know it might not be what you want, but it works as an approach to get a field/variable contents into a parameter